# Saving custom input values to sharepoint metadata columns

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have a list called Employees, I created a custom form for saving the data. The customs form holds five fields. Which are created using normal HTML input tags

1. Name: (input type = text)
2. ID: (input type= number)
3. Country:(input type = select which consist of options they are dynamically 
            added from metadata)
4. State: (input type = select which consist of options they are dynamically added based on the selection of Country field)
5. ContactNo: (input type = number)
6. Submit: (input type = button)

Columns in Employee Details

1. Name    (type = string)
2. Id      (type = number)
3. Country (type = managed metadata having Country Metdata)
4. State   (type = managed metadata having State Metadata)
5. ContactNo (type = number)

**Meta Data Management Structure**

```
EmployeesDetails(Term Set)
      Country(Term)
          India(Term)
          US(Term)
      State(Term)
          India(Term)
             New Delhi(Term)
             Karnataka(Term)
          US(Term)
             NewYork(Term)
             LosAngels(Term)
```

So when we are saving the record it should save to the corresponding columns. I am able to list state based on the selection of country from managed metadata. How can I save the record to the corresponding columns of state and country which are managed metadata columns using javascript?

Many regards

Answer (score 0):

Go the solution. Written in es6 for working include the babel transpiler, add the below script to your html file

```
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
```

**Note** the input fields are in html file

1. $("#country") = `<input type="text" id="country">`
2. $("#state")  =   `<input type="text" id="state">`

countryList and stateList are array consist of objects(termId and termName) in the form of

```
countryList = [{id:"322321asdjgash", name:"India"}, {id:"32232sdasd1asdjgash", name:"US"}]
```

The state list will be created based on the selection of country(for ex: US is selected then the stateList Array will be as shown below)

```
stateList = [{id:"12312qwdadeqwe", name:"Los Angels"}, {id:"53127362376asghdjhas", name:"Newyork"}]
```

```js
const onSubmitHandler = () => {
  let countryId = countryList.find(cL => cL.name === $("#country").val()).id,
      stateId   = stateList.find(sL => sL.name === $("#state").val()).id,
      // managed metadata field
      metaObject = {
        __metadata: {"type": "SP.Data.Employee_x005f_DetailsListItem"},
        Title: $("#title").val(),
        Country:{
          __metadata: {"type": "SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue"},
          Label: $("#country").val(),
          TermGuid: countryId,
          WssId: -1
        },
        State:{
          __metadata: {"type": "SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue"},
          Label: $("#state").val(),
          TermGuid: stateId,
          WssId: -1
        }
      };
$.ajax({
  url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +"/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Employee_Details')/items",
  method: "POST",
  data: JSON.stringify(metaObject),
  headers:{
    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
    "IF-MATCH": "*"
  },
  success: (data) => {
    console.log("success",data);
  },
  error: (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  }

})
}
```